# Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRApp'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

After import the Firebase.h file i wrote "[FIRApp configure]" on "- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions". While running on the simulator it is showing "Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRApp'". But if select "Generic iOS device" option for build, no error is coming. Build and Archive working as properly. But on local simulator issue is coming.I have to run the app on Simulator first for crash communications with Firebase server. Please give me solution.enter

Comment: Can you share your Podfile and if you did something with your build settings and scheme?

Comment: inserting "$(inherited)" on Framework search paths, Header search paths, Other linker flags.

Answer (score 27):

In `AppDelegate.m` file, you should import firebase like `#import <Firebase.h>` before `#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED` line.

As I understand, You probably get success on dev build because FlipperKit libraries are used for debugging and this #ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED if condition is satisfied. When you try to archive it will not be imported and the variables will be undeclared because #import <Firebase.h> remains in that if condition.

Comment: Perfect, it is works for me

Comment: It saves my day

Comment: This saved the day, thanks @Amir Doreh

Comment: Helped me fix my issue, because I had accidentally placed my `import <Firebase.h>` line within a different `#ifdef` statement!

Comment: #if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED for some

Answer (score 5):

FIRApp is moved (or initially was) to FirebaseCore framework. So.

`#import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>.`

Comment: Build is still failing for me after this change.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [this github comment](https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/issues/3008#issuecomment-954455155):

> What work for me
> Just add
> `#import <Firebase.h>` to the AppDelegate.h as well

Source:

Comment: Wow! Never thought it would be so trivial

Answer (score 1):

In the react native firebase docs (see here: https://rnfirebase.io/) it says put the `#import <Firebase.h>` at the top of the document. You imported `#import <Firebase.h>` below `#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED`, so you basically import firebase module if the `RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED` condition is true.

you should do :

```
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTAppSetupUtils.h>

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
#import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
#import <React/CoreModulesPlugins.h>
#import <React/RCTCxxBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <React/RCTFabricSurfaceHostingProxyRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenter.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter.h>
#import <ReactCommon/RCTTurboModuleManager.h>

#import <react/config/ReactNativeConfig.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem but I haven't `FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED`

```
#import <React/RCTAppSetupUtils.h>

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
#import <React/CoreModulesPlugins.h>
#import <React/RCTCxxBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <React/RCTFabricSurfaceHostingProxyRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenter.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter.h>
#import <ReactCommon/RCTTurboModuleManager.h>

#import <react/config/ReactNativeConfig.h>


static NSString *const kRNConcurrentRoot = @"concurrentRoot";

@interface AppDelegate () <RCTCxxBridgeDelegate, RCTTurboModuleManagerDelegate> {
  RCTTurboModuleManager *_turboModuleManager;
  RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter *_bridgeAdapter;
  std::shared_ptr<const facebook::react::ReactNativeConfig> _reactNativeConfig;
  facebook::react::ContextContainer::Shared _contextContainer;
}
@end
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7ob2.png)